# Add button to watch questions/get notified on edits, comments, etc

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, global-inbox, follow-post

I often have the situation that I read a question and leave a comment requesting an edit to provide more information by the OP.

Currently, I add the phrase that he/she should please also write a comment containing "@ByteCommander" to notify me when they're done. This is not optimal as it's additional typing and often the OP does not follow it.

I know that the star/favorites feature allows me to bookmark questions and see on my user profile site how many/which questions had a recent change. But I think this is pretty complicated. I don't want to fill up my list of favorites with tons of questions and I don't really want to check that section out regularly.

My suggestion is to add a button similar to the "watch"-button on GitHub that enables notifications on edits, answers and/or comments without ping to appear in my global inbox instead of being hidden somewhere down in my profile.

Do you think this would improve the usability of the sites and increase the question solving rate?
I do.

Comment: This is effectively implemented by the [Follow Questions and Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/335251) feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This has been discussed many times already and in many different forms.

The favorite questions functionality serves its purpose. If you want to do a more extended way of grouping or remembering your favorites, you should keep an own repository, possibly in your browser.

I understand this is not ideal since it doesn't get notifications like you do now. An option that could fix this is to subscribe to the RSS feed of the question, like [the feed from this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/259687) (See the right bottom corner for the RSS icon on almost every page). You can do this with a lot of online and offline RSS readers. You will receive updates from the question, you can group them and you can handle them as you wish.

Comment: Is there a link to the feed somewhere? Or will I have to edit it myself according to the question's id?

Comment: See the right bottom corner. There is a RSS icon.

Comment: Ah, yes! Did never notice it. Thank you for this suggestion!