# Inbox improvements are live

Tags: discussion, top-bar, global-inbox, announcements

### The feedback up until January 3<sup>rd</sup>, 2023 has been catalogued and handed over to the product team. Any further feedback or bug reports should be posted as a new question.

---

**TL;DR**: The [inbox improvements we previously announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382693/inbox-improvements-marking-notifications-as-read-unread-and-a-filtered-inbox-v) are now live (as of November 29th, 2022 13:30 UTC).

---

### Thank you to our beta testers!

A huge thank you to moderators who helped us beta-test these inbox changes! Your feedback was invaluable, and we could not be here without you.

### New features

This post will provide a short overview of the new features, focusing especially on a few special cases not covered in [the previous post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382693/inbox-improvements-marking-notifications-as-read-unread-and-a-filtered-inbox-v). The changes will be rolled out to all sites, unless mentioned otherwise in the feature list below.

We will post an update here when the changes will be released.

- **Marking notifications as read/unread**:

  - On all Stack Exchange top bars, *except for the ones on Area 51 and the chat sites*, the inbox dropdown will support individually marking messages as read/unread (or marking them all read at once), without needing to open the notification in a new tab/window.
  - Opening up the inbox will no longer automatically mark all messages as being read.
  - **Note**: opening the inbox in chat will automatically mark all messages as being read until the changes will be applied there.
- **Filtering to only show unread messages**: All Stack Exchange pages, *except for the inbox that is on the chat rooms listing, Area 51 pages, and stackexchange.com*, will support filtering to only show unread messages in the inbox.
- **New design**: On all Stack Exchange pages, *except for the inbox that is on the chat rooms listing and Area 51 pages*, the inbox will have a new design, updated to accommodate new buttons and improve readability.
- **Real-time inbox refreshing**:

  - All Stack Exchange pages, *except for the inbox that is on the chat rooms listing, Area 51 pages, and stackexchange.com*, will support real time refreshing of the inbox content.
  - If a new notification arrived while the inbox was opened, the user will have an option to refresh its content manually with a *refresh* button.
  - We avoid an immediate refresh not to disturb the users while they work on their notifications. This option is also available while working with multiple tabs open at the same time.
- **Unread messages in the global inbox**: The global inbox page will now highlight the unread items. It is also possible to mark the notifications as read by opening them in the global inbox.

[image: Inbox popup overview]

### FAQ

**Are you planning to bring these inbox improvements to chat as well?**

Yes, we plan to update the inbox on all Stack Exchange pages (including chat) to the new style. While 100% compatibility on all sites will be hard to achieve, disabling the new functionality on chat pages is just a temporary solution.

**Can I keep the current inbox functionality?**

No. However, depending on the feedback, we may introduce the option to keep the current behavior of marking all notifications as read when the inbox is opened. If you want us to implement this as an option, please let us know!

**Is this the final version of the inbox?**

No, this is our first inbox-related release. We have a backlog of inbox-related issues that we gathered during both internal and beta testing. We plan to incrementally improve the MVP after the public release of the feature, based on the community feedback and product needs.

### How should we share feedback on these changes?

If you have any questions, suggestions, or other feedback regarding the inbox improvements we've described here, please post it in an answer below. We'll be gathering feedback until the end of December 2022, after which we ask you to share any bug reports/feature requests by posting a separate question.

Comment: I'd like to remind folks of our request to **post your feedback and questions in answers below**. In order to keep things organized, comments that should be answers will be removed from time to time.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering why all but two answers have not been responded to by staff since early December, the team [is currently focusing on the Staging Ground release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384148/inbox-improvements-are-live?page=2#comment1282333_384442).

Comment: Since this is a large thread, if you are thinking of posting something and have not read existing posts to see if a similar post has already been made, you can try searching them using the search bar with "[`inquestion:384148 is:answer ...`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A384148+is%3Aanswer)".

Comment: I've gone through and catalogued all the feedback on this post already for the product team; we'll be going through it and prioritizing it to address in the next week or two. Any additional feedback on the inbox (bug reports/feature requests) should be posted as a separate post instead.

Comment: @V2Blast have this been forgotten? There is no activity for two months. (usually the devs put status tags as edits to the bug reports or features in the answers.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars: Not forgotten, just sort of put on hold for a bit. The devs working on this have been busy lately kicking off [Staging Ground beta 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423469/1478931). Once the dust has settled a bit, they should have more time to dedicate to going through the bugs and feature requests from this thread (which we're already tracking internally).

Comment: @V2Blast thanks, I'll ask again in three months.

Comment: @V2Blast maybe lock the question, if additional feedback should be posted elsewhere?

Comment: You might want to upvote the post that proposed 12 years ago the possibility to mark notifications as unread: [Enable marking a response as "unread"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64283/enable-marking-a-response-as-unread)

Answer (score 77):

> However, depending on the feedback, we may introduce the option to keep the current behavior of marking all notifications as read when the inbox is opened. If you want us to implement this as an option, please let us know!

[I already kinda did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382695/369802), but I don't mind letting you know again. So yes, please give me the option to mark all as read by just opening the inbox. If I really want to keep something and be annoyed by the indicator, I can then manually mark something as unread.

Comment: if it's a toggle, they'll just disable it in a few years because only 13k people used it

Comment: Is the one extra click now required to do this really too much? https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTQzi.png There isn't really a way for them to allow setting individual items as unread if every time you open the inbox it sets everything to read automatically.

Comment: @TylerH “Double-click” vs. “click, move mouse, click, move mouse, click” is a rather significant increase in the amount of interaction. 95% of the time when I want this, it’s because I’ve already seen the comment because I was already on the relevant page, so I just double-click. I would absolutely turn this on if available.

Comment: Would be nice if it was some form of checkbox/toggle next to the mark all as read rather than a profile settings thing

Comment: @TylerH even if everything is marked read by using the "mark all as read" button now, you can still mark individual items as unread again. So I'm not entirely getting what you mean by "There isn't really a way for them to allow setting individual items as unread if every time you open the inbox it sets everything to read automatically.", as that to me seems very much possible? I just only may need to keep something unread in like 0,05 percent of all notifications I get, so I personally much prefer extra clicks/movement to be limited to those cases and not the 99,95% of the time I don't need it

Comment: @Tinkeringbell If they made it so that opening the inbox menu marked everything as read, then even if you went and marked some items unread again, the next time you open your inbox menu, they'd be marked read. So not only would you have to keep marking them as unread each time you access the inbox, you also have to _remember_ which ones are unread to go and mark them as unread again. Which also isn't possible after a certain point when they get pushed off the menu and into the /inbox network page.

Comment: @TylerH ah, like that. Well the post itself said that if asked, they might provide, so I assume they can somehow mark the ones that were manually marked "unread" to stay that way, and not be dismissed when opening the inbox :) But yeah, it makes sense that this is a technical thing to keep in mind when building :)

Comment: Personally I like the notion of just removing the red number/indicator when you open it, while leaving the color difference on each individual item... I'm fairly confident most people who open and close to 'mark as read' as a convenience measure are more concerned about the red indicator on their top bar rather than actually marking every item as read _within_ the menu. I agree there's certainly some middle ground available for improvement here.

Comment: @TylerH While I realize the quote says “when the inbox is opened,” but it also says “the current behavior”—the current behavior is to mark them all as read when the inbox is _closed_. That eliminates the concern about previously-marked-unread items being shown as read the next time you open the inbox (it does imply that you’d have to mark them as unread over and over unless there’s logic to skip manually-marked-unread items, as Tinkeringbell suggests, but still, that’s “annoying” rather than “useless”).

Comment: @KRyan I don't see a difference between doing it when you open vs doing it when you close (and the current behavior is now "don't mark them all as read unless you click mark them all as read", which is instantaneous); the end result is still "next time I open the inbox menu, all my previously-marked-as-unread messages are now marked as read. The point here is what is unread should **persist** as unread until you either perform a 'mark individual item as read' action or perform a "mark all as read" action. Neither opening the inbox nor closing it count as such an action, nor should they.

Comment: I don't really care that the message stays marked as unread until i mark it, what i care about is getting rid of the red dot on my header notifying me of things i've literally already read and responded to. If it'd stop notifying me of comment replies to posts i'm literally currently looking at/reading it wouldn't be so bothersome.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell "so I assume they can somehow mark the ones that were manually marked "unread" to stay that way" - don't make that assumption. Doing this will be a **much** bigger change than giving an option to restore the old functionality (open the inbox, all are read).

Comment: @KevinB "If it'd stop notifying me of comment replies to posts i'm literally currently looking at/reading it wouldn't be so bothersome" - that sounds like something that would be better in it's own answer below, and not in the comments here (forgive me if it is already there).

Comment: i don't feel it's worth my effort

Comment: Please add this back! It may be opt-out feature, but having to click "mark as read" to remove the red dot is extremely annoying. Alternatively, add an option to hide that mark forever instead (less preferable for me, but still better than 3 clicks for nothing)

Answer (score 55):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Mark all notifications from a post as read after opening only one.

Sometimes I get a notification because a followed question is edited, has a comment and a new answer and maybe even closed which are 3-4 different inbox messages, but I only really need to open one.

Can we have a setting to mark all notifications from a single post as read when one is opened?

Comment: Honestly I would argue this is a bug because if the same user comments twice, only the most recent comment is shown, but both comments count toward the notification count bubble, and you have to click 'mark all as read' to get the bubble to go away.

Comment: It should however group those notifications together, so that it's clear there are multiple ones and all of them will be marked as read. Otherwise it'll be very confusing when following multiple active discussions.

Comment: To clarify, you are asking for "click on a notification for a single question, mark all the notifications for that question as read, but **not** for notifications on answers on the same page"? In this case, would there still be value to indicate on page load what were the comments that had notifications that were just marked as read?

Comment: @YaakovEllis if I've understood you correctly, yes.

Comment: the inbox makes me go insane. 3 notifications from same post. I have to click 3 times so everything is unread.

Comment: Related: [Inbox auto-read - a userscript to mark inbox notifications as read automatically](https://stackapps.com/q/9606/10706)

Comment: I agree it feels like a bug. It doesn't make any sense that the red number of notifications will be different from the number of notifications shown to you when you expand it. And if this answer is implemented directly, it's very likely to miss the new comments or answers on the page, or waste time hunting for them, when you're opening the only one in the inbox that is shown to you.

Comment: now, when marking the newest notification as read, [all related notifications are also marked as read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390795/1221265). I hope that solves the problem!

Comment: @marrados [I love it when a feature request comes together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tr4C.jpg)

Answer (score 28):

[support](/questions/tagged/support) / [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Is there keyboard binding for marking messages as read? If not, can one be implemented in the future?

Some times I am already looking at the post where I got a reply. Since I already know what the notification is telling me about, I can just press <kbd>i</kbd> -> <kbd>Esc</kbd> to open and close the inbox drawer and clear the notification.

I would like to keep being able to use the keyboard when possible and not reach for my mouse. And especially for clearing several notifications, I would prefer to avoid clicking a lot in quick succession. Working with a keyboard is more comfortable than clicking a lot.

Comment: We are planning to add keyboard bindings for mark-all-read, refresh inbox (when it is available). Might also be good to have one for "mark all messages read for the current post" (though that one will be a bit trickier).

Comment: @YaakovEllis I'd be happy with something like "mark read for post 1, 2, 3...x". Right now **i** -> **1** will [open the first notification item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bw1L.png). Maybe something like **i** -> **Shift** + **1** (or other modifier) can clear the notification.

Answer (score 24):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

If you scroll the Inbox scrollbar all the way to the bottom, all of the items disappear; I'd expect the last few items to remain on the screen. Scrolling back up re-displays the items.

[image: blank Inbox after scrolling to the bottom]

- Browser: Google Chrome, Version 107.0.5304.122 (Official Build) (64-bit); can also reproduce with Microsoft Edge, Version 107.0.1418.62 (Official build) (64-bit)
- OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
- Screen resolution: 1920 x 1080

Comment: can you please add  your browser, OS, and approximate screen resolution (wide/narrow, etc)?

Comment: I have also noticed this bug.
Opera 93.0, macOS 10.14.6, either wide or narrow.

Comment: @YaakovEllis I can reproduce with same browser and OS but it doesn't look like a specific browser issue. When you scroll all the way down, you don't see the empty page?

Comment: Can reproduce as well. It seems like it might have something to do with the `margin-top: 100%` on the `.inbox-se-link-new` class on the last child `<li>` of the rendered list (that houses the "Go to full inbox" link).

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox 107.0 on Windows 10 (1920x1080 resolution)

Comment: Chrome, Brave and Firefox on Ubuntu 22.04 (all up-to-date, from deb) - confirmed on all three. Doesn't depend on screen width. Repro's even on phone emulation via devtools. `li.inbox-item.inbox-se-link-new.js-see-all-inbox-items` (last `li` of notifications, containing "Go to full inbox" link) is what's causing the shift; removing `margin-top: 100%` from it fixes the issue.

Comment: Can repro on Mac Mojave, Safari 15

Comment: @YaakovEllis FYI, see above comment where someone tracked down the cause for the bug.

Comment: can repro on MAC ventura MS Edge.

Answer (score 23):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

A minor request: the wording "mark all read / unread" looks a bit off. Can it be updated to read "mark all **as** read / unread"? The latter is much more common than the current choice — see the [Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/12516?hl=en-CA), [Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mark-a-message-as-read-or-unread-59b44298-08c2-4eb7-8128-ea0fb7f52720), or [GitHub Notifications](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/managing-subscriptions-and-notifications-on-github/viewing-and-triaging-notifications/managing-notifications-from-your-inbox#triaging-options)' wording for a couple of major examples. Keeping the wording consistent across products and services for common actions ensures a smooth user experience.

Comment: I agree with this, to me reading "mark all read" implies doing something with the read items rather than marking all items as read

Comment: yup, indeed, @WhatsThePoint. Since in "mark all read" the last word is an adjective, first of all, it implies a noun should follow it (for example, "items"), and that implies an action should follow it (for example, "for deletion" / "as unread"). A correct phrase the current wording would look something like this: "mark all read items as unread", a shortcut for which is precisely the proposed wording: "mark all as unread" :)

Comment: And so it is done. Good suggestion - I believe the original intent was to make the button slightly shorter, but the clarity of the message is more important.

Answer (score 23):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

**Remember my preference for all/unread (top-left)**

When I switch from 'All' to 'Unread' in the top-left, that state is maintained for the lifetime of the page, but not after a refresh.

I pretty much don't care about notifications that I've already read. I prefer the unread view as the default.

If this setting was persistent, then unread could stay as my default state after I changed it once.

Answer (score 21):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

In the spirit of the promise made in [Providing a JavaScript API for userscripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372956/786798) back in December 2021, will an effort be made to provide userscript authors with a way to hook into the inbox? If not, please, at least ensure that the logical units of the feature have ids (or `js-*` classes depending on the team's preferred style) set on them so we do not have to rely on brittle CSS selectors that are subject to break at any point.

Comment: hooks into the inbox are a longer-term goal - if you have specific hooks you'd like to see, please list them here. In the meantime, happy to put `js-*` classes on any element of interest. They should all be there, if one is needed, let us know please.

Comment: That's great to hear, @YaakovEllis - let me examine the version that just went live. When I come up with a list of what areas are of key importance, I'll surely add the suggestions to the post. Extending the top menu bar has traditionally been a pain point for script developers, so having some hooks at least in the long run will go a long way. Heck, if nothing else, that would mean we would be able to easily prototype features we'd like to see implemented :)

Comment: At a cursory glance, the markup is pretty good, actually (major thanks - items, wrappers, and controls all have appropriate classes) - that basically leaves us thinking about the stable API (exposing the controller to the StackExchange global, maybe?) only. Need to read through the source code first, though - will get back to ya'll with suggestions.

Answer (score 20):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Explicitly indicate the number of comments in the notification, so that the numbers add up

Currently, when multiple comments are made on a single post, the notification number will be incremented once for each comment, but the actual dropdown will consolidate those into a single notification from the time it was last opened/marked read. For instance, if one post of mine got three comments and another one of mine got two, the inbox number will be incremented by 5 but only two entries will show in the list (for each of the two posts).

It would be nice if each notification entry that's actually multiple consolidated into one would show the number of notifications that have been consolidated. I often get confused when opening the list which said there are five unread notifications but only seeing one, two, or three ones actually listed, and it makes for poor UX. Showing the number would more clearly indicate how they add up.

Comment: Yes! Although I would rather see them all as individual notifications, grouped in a tree, that you could choose to mark as read/unread all at once or individually.

Comment: Came to MSE to report this as a bug, especially because once you click on that one consolidated notification and read the comment, another unread notification will appear in the dropdown and this will continue until you've clicked each of the new unread notifications for comments on the same post in turn.

Comment: now, when marking the newest notification as read, [all related notifications are also marked as read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390795/1221265). For now we're not planning to add a number of consolidated notifications in the inbox, but I agree it'd be nice to have. I hope that solves the problem!

Answer (score 18):

After playing around with it for a couple of hours I have to say I **really like it**!

It's a welcome improvement to something that was always an annoyance, so thank you to the team for implementing.

One enhancement I'd *personally* like is for where you have several new notifications all linking to the *same* question - for example, notifications about several new comments and/or one or more new answers on the same question, I'd prefer to have *all* notifications that relate to this same question marked as read when I click on any of them.

One rather big annoyance is that if I select to show only new messages, this is not remembered - if I refresh the browser window it's back to showing all. Can this setting not be saved, it's a bit redundant otherwise?

And a very minor niggle (no biggie) is when choosing to view only unread messages, I wonder if the window could be sized appropriately – i.e., if no new messages, then don't show a large blank area but increase its size until it reaches the max (could it be user-draggable like an answer text box?).

Comment: Thanks for the positive feedback! We definitely have "figure out a better way to handle merged notifications" on our list of things to address, as well as remembering th euser's setting for filter.

Comment: This sounds very similar to my [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384162/175002)! Great minds and all that!

Comment: @YaakovEllis please come to the conclusion that the best way to handle it is to not merge at all

Answer (score 18):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

**Mark notification as read if opened in new tab by any means** (including right click menu -> open in new tab).

If one left clicks on an unread item, the relevant post/comment/whatever is opened and the item is marked as read (at least sometimes, not sure what the exact conditions are...).

Can we please get the same behaviour if we open the item in a new tab (e.g. by right clicking and selecting "open link in new tab")? At the moment, this just opens the relevant post in a new tab, but the item stays unread and one needs to open the inbox yet another time to mark the item as read...

Comment: We spent some time on this in the dev process, and have it working for left-click, ctrl-left-click (open in new tab), and middle-click (open in a new tab). The challenge with "right click - open in new tab" is that there is no way to only catch it for "open in new tab" but not for the other right click menu options. So it is all-or-none with right click, and we chose not to mark as read then, because there are other legitimate uses of right click that dont include opening a new tab, and there are 2 other new tab options available (ctrl-left and middle).

Comment: @YaakovEllis Middle click is not easily available via touchpad and having to use use the keyboard just to open a notification in a new tab is annoying. Can there a setting to enable right click to mark as read? Or an mechanism via the api to mark a specific inbox item as read? Then we could simply build our own inbox which would work as we need it to work.

Comment: Seems trivial to do if a parameter is attached to the URL. The same way clicks from the side bar are tracked by adding `lq=1` (for linked) or `rq=1` (for related). In a similar fashion, links from inbox messages parameter can indicate "mark a message as read after requesting this URL". Then it would not matter which mode of opening the page is used.

Comment: @VLAZ This would be awesome! And would also work from self-build inboxes!

Comment: Wouldn't it be far more useful to mark notifications as read at the visiting page without extra parameters? Why should i have to click on a notification in the inbox to cause it to be read when I load the page it's pointing at outside of the inbox? 99% of the time notifications i get are for things on pages I'm already on.

Comment: Came here to report exactly this. **Drives. Me. Nuts.** Right-Click > Open in new tab is my usual flow for dealing with notifications.

Comment: @KevinB perhaps. It's a possible way to do it. However, then you might miss that something happened on the page if you didn't see the notification but just navigated there for another reason. Especially on long Q&As on Meta, it's *very* easy to miss if a comment or even a new answer was posted. I'd rather not clear out all the notifications for, say, 7 comments on 3 different posts and two new posted answers just because I went to check something in the question.

Answer (score 16):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)? [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)? [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Clicking "mark as read" on a collapsed multiple notifications item should mark all of them as read or mark the shown one as read and show a previously hidden unread item**.

Currently, this is what happens:

1. Get multiple notifications from a single post (say, 3).
2. The inbox icon has 3 in red circle, and when I open it, there is a single collapsed unread item.
3. Click "mark as read" on it. Now **all items shown are marked as read, but the inbox icon still indicates 2 unread items.**
4. When I close and open the inbox, *then* it shows another unread item from the same post.

I think the behavior at step 3 should be changed to one of the following:

- all associated items are marked as read (and the inbox counter decremented by that amount);
- only the shown item is marked as read, and the next unread item from the same post shows up immediately.

Comment: now, when marking the newest notification as read, [all related notifications are also marked as read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390795/1221265). I hope that solves the problem!

Answer (score 15):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

My impression is that with the old design, when I was notified about an unread chat message, reading it would turn off the inbox notification for it.

Not so with the new design. It notifies me of an "unread" chat message even after I have read it and even replied to it.

In some more detail, this is different from the "bring back the old behavior" requests in that I think this use case is separate, and easier to reason about:

If there is a notification balloon in chat, I have an unread message, and the inbox should notify me about that.

If there is not a notification balloon in chat, that message is now by definition not unread.

For some more context, I have several browser tabs open with the chat rooms I'm participating in. So I basically never click an inbox notification to be taken to an unread chat message because that would duplicate a tab I already have open.

Comment: You need to click the inbox item or the envelope icon near it in order to mark it as read, that's a new functionality. (Before all items were marked read when you just opened the inbox.)

Comment: Indeed, but when there was a single message I was notified about and it was a chat message, reading that message in chat was enough. The hassle to mark each chat message read twice is unwelcome and unnecessary.

Answer (score 14):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[design](/questions/tagged/design)

"Read" notifications are literally grayed-out, making the entire box gray.
This feels completely out of place, it's the darkest element on the page (on Meta and light mode SO):

> [image]

I'd prefer it to have some opacity, for example:

> [image]

(Crossposted from my [SO Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421743/message-inbox-full-of-read-messages-is-very-dark-and-out-of-place) after I found this announcement)

Comment: Personally, I would go about this in a different way: All read messages show normally (like the 2nd one you have, without bold), but the unread ones have an highlighted background (and maybe bold text).

Comment: That also works, yea!

Comment: It's a feature, not a bug. Yes, I also [said about this on the original announcement](/a/383016/578924). And no, IMO the opacity makes some strain to the eyes. @IsmaelMiguel This is exactly what I proposed, to keep the old design which is consistent, more unique and not trying to be GMail.

Answer (score 13):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

### Expand the filtering functionality

I think an option to filter for certain SE network(s) would be helpful. I keep an eye on my Stack Overflow notifications, but I miss them on the other networks from time to time. Having that option would make it easier for me to circle back to them.

If you decided this is a valid request, then you may want to implement a filter for different types of notifications, i.e. comments, chat, etc. while you're at it.

Comment: That can be done however I don't think inbox is so big that it can accomodate a filter. If we insert a filter inbox will look like a lot in very less space in my opinion.

Comment: @JitendraSingh I think from the UI standpoint, a lot can be done to make it minimalistic yet easy to navigate. Off the top of my head, add a small button on top which will open the filter as an overlay on top of the notifications so it doesn't spill all over the page.

Comment: @JitendraSingh I think a row of site icons, like the one that appears in Achievements dropdown when you get rep on multiple sites, would work great. After loading notifications you could build a site list and display icons only for those sites that are currently in the Inbox.

Answer (score 13):

### Update the cached count of notifications once the dropdown is opened

Sometimes, a stale number of unread notifications will show in the dropdown, which happens when one or more notifications received since the number was loaded have been marked read from a different instance of the site (another window or tab on the same device, or a different device) but the number in the first instance hasn't had a chance to update. Perhaps it didn't receive the WebSocket ping that updates the number (because, e.g., the device was put to sleep, briefly lost its Internet connection, or the browser put the tab to sleep to save resources), or perhaps the user's browser loads in a cached version of the page with a stale count.

In that case, when I open the dropdown (successfully), the actual current state of my notifications being read/unread are loaded in, but the number on the button still reads the old stale number. This creates a UX inconsistency where the number displayed doesn't match the actual number.

Currently, the only workaround I've tested is to click the button to mark all notifications as read. In the case I've encountered, where it showed a number of 1 but the actual dropdown showed nothing unread, clicking that updated the number and made it disappear. However, this causes undesired effects if one has deliberately left unread notifications. Another workaround is to fully reload the page, but this is a bad solution for someone on a slow connection or one that imposes a heavy data cap.

When the dropdown is opened and the current live status of unread and read notifications is loaded, can the number shown in the button please be updated to show the actual count in case it was stale since the last load?

Comment: I encounter this frequently when I have multiple Stack Exchange tabs open. A call to `/topbar/inbox` appears to be made on first click of the inbox on a given page, which loads a fresh copy of the notifications pane content, but the actual notification number does not update to match its state, creating a mismatch. [GIF version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PaYY.gif)

Answer (score 12):

I find the new design quite confusing, because the bottom button `Go to full inbox` is white. As such it gives me the impression, that the blue-grayish items are actually unread, because they have a different colour, and the white (unread) items are read. The bold-face font does not really help either and the icons are too far on the right, so it takes a second glance to confirm.

I think it could already help, to colour the bottom button in the same  background colour as the rest of the design.

Edit:
I also just noticed that this contrasts directly with the *Achievements* tab, which uses white as a background colour for read items, and the blue-ish/grayish tint for new items.

Please fix this :)

[image]

Comment: Yes, I also [said about this on the original announcement](/a/383016/578924). As for the buttons, it's rather confusing because they have no borders – a huge problem of many modern designs. If you make it gray, it would still blend with gray items.

Answer (score 12):

At least on StackOverflow, I noticed that I have to manually mark the notification as read which is kind of annoying. Previously once I open the messages menu, the unread count notification automatically went away.

[image]

Is there a setting using which we can revert to previous behavior?

Comment: See the answer to "Can I keep the current inbox functionality?" in the announcement: "No. However, depending on the feedback, we may introduce the option to keep the current behavior of marking all notifications as read when the inbox is opened. If you want us to implement this as an option, please let us know!"

Comment: @V2Blast - Thanks and yes please. I would very much like to have that option. Right now it is an annoying distraction and IMHO once I have clicked on the message icon on the top button bar, I think the job is already done. Having to explicitly mark a message as read is an additional step for me which is not adding any value regarding my interaction with the site.

Comment: The added value is when you see new messages but don't interact with them (like reading the full comment, viewing the answer to a followed question, etc), then you will probably want to look at them later. With the new functionality it is easy to see which items you have not 'completed' yet. Once you do interact (i.e., click on the message) then it is marked as read automatically. This is the same as for example an e-mail inbox, when you open your inbox it does not cause all new emails to be marked as read.

Comment: @Marijn If i want to interact with a thing i will remember, if i dont remember it was probably not so important. I get it that SE wants more interaction but honestly I dont. It would have been many many times useful if i had just stopped to react to other people. I mean if somebody wants a clarification fine but really anything more ask a question.

Answer (score 12):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

**Add a way to sort unread items to the top**

Currently, both read and unread notifications are sorted in the order they were received — it is, of course, expected behavior (and one can always filter out read items), but it would be great to be able to split the notifications inbox modal in two groups: read and unread items.

Grouping unread items allows one to quickly determine what else needs attention without the need to scroll back-n-forth through the list (which can be pretty long for active users) searching for items that might still require attention.

As a precedent, there is an "inbox type" setting in the Gmail web interface:

[image: screenshot of the Gmail web interface "inbox type" setting]

We could have something similar: either as a dropdown with sort options or as a profile preference (how it is implemented is not particularly important).

Comment: Is there a reason the current filter to show only unread items is insufficient for this purpose?

Comment: @V2Blast the need to context-switch, mostly. Currently, you can only toggle between "all", which has items sorted by date (thus, sometimes making it a bit hard to find unread items quickly, especially for an active user like myself), and "unread", which obviously leaves out read items (thus necessitating another switch back to "all" once a user is done with checking unread items. Having a way to get the best of both worlds would be nice - it's far from a critical FR, just a QoL thing.

Answer (score 10):

As an occasional user and mod on a small site, most of my notifications are comments on answers and such where I basically interact by opening the inbox, reading the comment, deciding if I want to do something, and then leaving the site.

I get that you want to get more engagement to the site, and this functionality seems pretty useful for the highly engaged users who have lots of notifications and want to interact with them.  But for me, this just adds another click - one I don't want to make.

Please bring back the old functionality as an option for people like me - and frankly it should be the *default* option.  This method is too difficult to discover for new users - the "mark a notification as read" button (the little envelope) is not intuitive - and new users are the ones who will find this the least useful.

From my point of view, the alternative is for me to add custom CSS to remove the red bubble entirely, which will have the opposite impact of what you're hoping, interaction-wise.

Comment: Just clicking on the message should also mark it as read (and also redirect). You should only need to click on the envelope if you want to toggle the read status without redirecting.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Understood, but I usually don't click on it. When I say read I mean I use the inbox as my content - so many of my comments are trivial things that I can dismiss and ignore.  Open the inbox, glance, close inbox is my workflow.

Comment: It would be nice if there were some statistics (ideally from _before_ the change) how often people actually open the inbox but not click on (all) the unread items. I suspect most people _do_ actually click on the inbox items. For myself many comments I get are >100 characters and therefore cut off in the inbox, so even if I only want to read the comment and do nothing with it I need to click on the item. For short items I usually also click because I'm interested in what happens with a followed question or I want to reply to or upvote someone's comment.

Comment: I wonder how much this remark will be heard - mine is similar - on a thread that's dedicated to this subject.  Seems to me the people coming here are going to be weighted on having interest in this feature.  How is SE going to account for statistical self-selection bias?  You need to be a pretty savvy user to know stackexchange meta, not <your site's> meta is where you can expect feedback and dialog about the framework's UI.  I don't mind this feature at all, *as long as it is not the option I am forced to use.*  If I can toggle a setting that says, "do as before", I am happy.

Comment: @Joe the workflow for your scenario right now is to use the read all button. We hope to add keyboard shortcuts as well, and are considering a personal preference to revert to "mark all as read on open".

Answer (score 10):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

If all of my messages are marked as "Read" and I click on the option "Inbox (Unread)" I see the following:

[image: screenshot of the open notifications modal with empty space taking up most of its height]

Can we have a message something like "No unread messages" or "All messages have been read by you" or something like that instead of this white space? Also, just like [the other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384209/1052107) stated, please change the "Go to full inbox" background colour as it makes the appearance worse.

Comment: Agreed. Although I'd prefer a positive message, along the lines of "All messages have been read" or "You're up to date", rather than the double-negative. Also pointing out that the big white space is what it looks like when waiting for messages to load - so it can be misleading.

Answer (score 9):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Accessibility of the filter components

Right now, the clickable area of the filter functionality is very small.

This is the clickable area for the dropdown; it’s only the arrow on its own, when I would have expected the full *“Inbox (all)”* text to be clickable since that’s what I am switching :

[image: Clickable area on the arrow for the dropdown]]

Similarly, within the drop down the clickable area is also smaller than I would have expected. It’s only the text that is clickable:

[image: Clickable area within the dropdown]]

I would have expected here that the area where the checkmark icon is being displayed is also clickable. This would help being able to select the other options since in my first attempt, I clicked a few pixels too far to the left of “Unread” and nothing happened.

Comment: Thank you for your idea! We adjusted the clickable area as per your suggestion.

Comment: @marrados Thanks a lot, it’s much better now 

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Very inconsistent count for the Refresh button when toggling the state of a message.

When changing from read to unread or vice versa it some times changes the count for the "Refresh (<number of unread messages>)" button, other times it does not.

I cannot find any consistency in it. See this short video, See how marking a message unread will only some times show "Refresh (1)". And marking a message unread will only some times change to "Refresh (0)".

[image: Video showing toggling one message as read or unread repeatedly which only some times leads to an updated Refresh button.]

Does not seem to be related to just clicking many times. Happens even if you click one time. Some times you get no update:

[image: Video showing toggling only one message as unread once. The Refresh button does not show up.]

Other times it does work on the first click:

[image: Video showing toggling only one message as unread once. The Refresh button shows up with a count of one.]

Comment: Noticed this too, from what I can gather, when you mark it as unread, the code thinks there is new message, so showing the "Refresh" button.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard yes. I feel like the Refresh button showing up is probably the real bug here. But it's also inconsistent when it does that.

Answer (score 9):

No-one's going to upvote this right at the bottom of the list, but I have to say after a week of giving this a chance…

I absolutely hate the new behaviour.

It has seemingly forgotten the entire advantage of tabbed browsing.

Clicking the envelope doesn't open the message, clicking the message header doesn't mark it as read. This does not work. I have to read it, then mark it as read. Not even the most basic mail app falls this short.

It's just adding more clicks for no benefit, imnsho.
Yet another new paradigm to learn. Two separate interactions for each message.
I just want the count to go away as soon as I start to interact with it & each to mark itself read if I click it *to open in a new tab*. I send every new message out to a new tab, then go through them. I don't need to then have to go back to the menu to tell it I'm reading the things I already asked it to read.

Comment: Sorry to hear that it hasn't been working for you. But...clicking the message opens it and marks it as read. Clicking the envelope marks it as read without opening it. If this is not working for you, then there is a local error with the execution of the script for you. Please give your browser version, etc (as it works fine for me on all browsers where I try it). The only type of "open" action that right now wont mark it as read is "right click > open in new tab". But middle click or ctrl-click should mark it as read while opening it on a new tab.

Comment: @YaakovEllis -  I'm on Mac Mojave, Safari 14.1.4 [which I'm aware is technically out of date]. I always 'open in new tab', never click though in the same tab, so I guess that's the bug I'm hitting. I just tried variants on a theme of 'open' & as far as I can see, only 'send my current tab to the new URL'  dismisses the message & header count. I only had one message - yours above - in the queue when I tried that.

Comment: Our challenge with handling "right click > open in a new tab" is that there is no way in the browser (that we were able to discover) to know that this is what you did after you right-clicked. We were left with either "every right click marks as read, no matter what you did (or even if you did nothing)", or "right click does not at all mark as read".

Comment: Now - someone else above complained about the same thing - that this is their primary way to mark as read (this being the only option on many tablets). And it is something that we have to consider - whether it is fair to users to mark as read for any right-click.

Comment: We are also considering trying to address this (though not right away) with functionality that would mark all inbox items read relating to the question/answer being opened (and preferably also indicate on-screen what the previously-unread items had been). This feels like a superior solution to me as it doesn't require guessing the intention of the reader on a right-click, and also takes care of all related inbox items at the same time. But it will have to wait it's turn for implementation.

Comment: I'm not 'technically' right clicking. I'm using a 3rd party mouse with a non-standard button config, but what it's *actually* sending to the OS is as though I Cmd/clicked a link. This in itself is a 'valid' macOS/Safari command, set in prefs as 'open link in new tab'. I'm aware that feels like it adds complexity, but I have tested a true Cmd/click & the behaviour is identical.

Comment: One usage pattern that is now possible that I have tried and often use now, is to just have one tab open. Open the inbox, click on an item, it loads in the same tab and is marked as read. You no longer have to open up lots of other tabs (since the inbox marks all the messages as read right away, and this is the way to use it). You can go one by one.

Comment: "I have tested a true Cmd/click & the behaviour is identical" - then this is probably a quirk with your particular browser. In all that I have tested, ctrl-click marks it as read. Disclaimer: I develop on a windows machine, and ever since Apple stopped offering Safari on Windows, I have had no way to test Safari (though others on the team can do so , and I'll try to enlist their help on this when we are able to get to it).

Comment: I appreciate it's a potential working method - but years of habit have nbeen that if I have a tab, it needs my attention - maybe now, maybe tomorrow; but I do cycle through them to see if they have any unannounced activity, which they often do. It's become a simple 'Open I want to know, closed, fugettaboudit' with the very occasional  'following' for something I feel may move long term, but not this week.

Comment: @YaakovEllis - [sorry, keep forgetting to tag you] Mac does't use ctrl/click except to open the contextual menu [an alternative to right click for those used to trackpads] so it's not something I can test on this platform. Also, no middle click [which I think is a nix thing? can't test]. --- Lemme just jump onto this from Chrome [whilst holding up garlic & religious symbols;) … OK, that behaves differently… but not enough to persuade me to ever use it, sorry:\ So, it appears something is non-standard, but I don't have the expertise to tell what.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Have you considered adding some parameter to the url as suggested by VLAZ in this comment https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384148/inbox-improvements-are-live#comment1281754_384266 ?

Comment: This is starting to feel like the 'Tested with Internet Explorer' days :\

Comment: @Tetsujin, ahem: "I'm on Mac Mojave, Safari 14.1.4 [which I'm aware **is technically out of date**]. We do test on the browsers that we support.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz adding a parameter is something else that we are considering. We would prefer not to as historically we have tried to avoid this, as it can leak into other things (even if we clear the param on the client or through a redirect). But is is another option.

Comment: @YaakovEllis -I just dragged a Monterey M1 into the room. It works on that. I'm now feeling as abandoned as the iOS app. I'll delete this & make my way to the old folks' home… [I'm still on this OS because of my professional life - I have 10 grand's-worth of equipment that will not work on anything newer].

Comment: @Tetsujin anyway - even though your browser is not supported, it is still a scenario that we would _like_ to support. I appreciate your trying it out and taking the time to give feedback. And hope that we will _eventually_ be able to have it addressed to your liking.

Comment: @YaakovEllis - I do appreciate your efforts. Please take much of my 'old curmudgeon' caricature as tongue in cheek. ;)

Comment: @YaakovEllis i think i'm having this same issue, on iOS chrome? I click the notification, it takes me to the comment, the notification stays unread. I'd hope the most recent version of chrome on iOS would be supported,

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Description:

Someone replied to one of my answers. I see a red 1 on my inbox icon. I click on the inbox icon and I see the new message listed along with others I've already read. I click on the link to the new message and get taken to the new comment below my answer. That all seems correct.

However, despite having now seen and read the new message by clicking on its link in the inbox dropdown, the red 1 is still being shown and the message is still shown as unread.

If I click on the "new" message link a second time then finally the red 1 goes away and the message is listed as read.

I would expect the message to appear as read after clicking its link in my inbox the first time. It should not take two views of the same message to mark it as read.

I can of course click on the little envelope icon to the right of the message instead of clicking on the message a second time to mark it as read but that shouldn't be necessary either.

This issue has happened for each new message I've received today since this change went live.

---

Updated Info on this issue:

This morning I refreshed my browser on stackoverflow.com. The inbox icon had a red 3 on it. I clicked on the mailbox icon and while there was a red 3, the inbox only showed one new message (from this post). I clicked the envelope icon and the red 3 changed to a 2. I clicked the link for the new message and was taken here. I clicked the inbox icon and now I see the message I clicked (marked as read) and a second message from this post (marked as unread). This time I just clicked the unread message link and I was taken back to the comments below this post. The red 2 changed to a 1. So one more time I clicked on the inbox icon and now I see the two read messages I've just clicked on and now a third unread message for this post. Finally I click on the 3rd message link and there's no more red number but now I see only one recent message from this post (marked as read).

This is so confusing. Let me try to summarize what I've seen so far:

1. It seems while viewing meta.stackexchange.com that clicking the link for an unread message does correctly mark the message as read and reduce the red number on the inbox icon.
2. For me, while on the main stackoverflow.com site, clicking the link for an unread message does not mark the message as read nor does it reduce the red number on the inbox icon. A second click on the same link does mark it as read and it does reduce the red number on the inbox icon. Clicking the envelope icon next to an unread message does correctly mark the message as read.
3. Getting multiple messages about the same post results in undesired behavior. The red number shows the total number of new messages but the inbox only shows one new message initially. Clicking the new message link results in one additional message for the post appearing in the inbox. This repeats until all new messages for that post have been clicked. At which point the inbox shows only one (read) message for the post.

Comment: If you click on the "read" envelope, wait half a second, and then click on the message, does the same thing happen? Or is the "read" status on the second page accurate now?

Comment: I'll have to try that on the next message I get. But no one should have to do two clicks to get the inbox status updated correctly. I'll reply when I can.

Comment: ok, thanks. Also be sure to do a hard refresh as well when you get a chance.

Comment: @YaakovEllis - this, to me, is an unwanted behaviour. The act of clicking the link to visit the message should in itself be the signal to mark it as read & clear the indicator number [assuming only one message] or reduce the count if multiple.

Comment: To be clear, clicking the link to visit the message does send a "message-read" to the server. This is how we designed it to work. This is how it works for me (I haven't been able to repro this). I am trying to figure out why it isn't working for this user

Comment: @YaakovEllis I just added a new section to the end of my post with new details. It seems different sites (stackoverflow.com vs meta.stackexchange.com) behave differently.

Comment: @YaakovEllis - I now see my issue is part of the 'open in new tab' behaviour mentioned elsewhere, which doesn't refresh the count.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Is there a formal place to submit bug reports on these inbox issues? After 6 weeks I am getting really frustrated dealing with these inbox bugs many times a day. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Safari 15.5, Mac OS 12.4

Clicking on the message to open the notification's linked post does *not* mark the message as read, only clicking the envelope (or clicking "mark all read") does.

Comment: Would it be possible to check in the dev console (F12) and see if you get any console errors when you try this. And on the network tab, see if you have any calls being made to `/topbar/mark-inbox-as-read`?

Comment: `WebSocket connection to 'wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/' failed: WebSocket is closed due to suspension.`

Comment: Though, it just started working - did you fix it? :)

Comment: we didnt change anything

Answer (score 7):

So I'm on a question that I've left a comment on and someone responds to my comment with an @. I read the comment, respond, and move on to another tab. That new tab now has a notification informing me of the comment I just responded to. I'm not positive, but I'm pretty sure the old inbox did this too, however with the old inbox this was at least clearable with double clicking the icon. Now, I have to click the icon, *wait for the inbox to open and load*, then find the "mark all as read" button and click it. I understand it's just a simple extra step, but it's not so simple when the dialog isn't instant, it's just getting in the way.

If it would stop notifying me of things I've already dealt with it wouldn't be getting in my way nearly every time I get a notification.

Comment: "*I'm not positive, but I'm pretty sure the old inbox did this too*" it did, yes.

Comment: But the old inbox marked things as dealt with if you had opened the inbox and chosen not to do anything about them, so a spurious notification (or an uninteresting one) cost no extra time beyond viewing it in the drop-down and then clicking away. That was the correct behaviour; the new inbox doesn't respect my choice to ignore something.

Comment: @kaya3 100%. I'd prefer the old functionality where it'd go away much easier. however, I'm pretty sure there's next to no chance we'll get that back. so... maybe we can instead get it to just ping us less for things we've obviously already seen to lessen the interruption.

Answer (score 6):

[support](/questions/tagged/support) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

When clicking entries in the "unread" filter, sometimes the entry disappears and the link doesn't get opened.

This has happened to me for primary-click (open in same tab) and middle-click (open in new tab).

In certain scenarios, this doesn't happen. I haven't figured out the exact details on when it happens. I'll keep experimenting and listing my findings.

Comment: Yeah, happens to me too. Strangely, doing that for an unread notification on the All filter both marks as read *and* opens the tab, but on the Unread filter it marks as read without opening the tab.

Comment: "Sometimes"? I've _never_ had this fail to happen; the entry _always_ disappears without opening the link when in "unread" mode. (My browser of choice is Brave)

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

Opening a message using keyboard shortcut does not mark it as read.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Have one unread message. You can just toggle the top one to be unread.
2. Press <kbd>I</kbd> for Inbox -> <kbd>1</kbd> to go to the first message (or <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, etc for other messages).

Expected: Opening a message marks it as read.
Actual: It does not. However, left-clicking with the mouse does mark the message as read when opening it.

Comment: Thank you for reporting it! We have it in our backlog - it wasn't included in the first release, but we will implement it. We also plan to add keyboard shortcuts for all the new actions.

Comment: Was it ever fixed?

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

**Change All/Unread (top-left) to a better control than a dropdown menu**

Why is this control a dropdown menu when there's only 2 options? It takes 2 clicks to change something that should only take 1.

The clickable area is also very small which is bad for accessibility.

It would be better as some kind of toggle control.

Comment: There are already requests to allow for more options (for example, site filtering). IMO, better leave it as is and let SE expand on  the dropdown.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I don't see any request that would strictly involve adding additional dropdown options. If there are more that make sense, then fine. I can't think of any.

Comment: [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384152/786798) :)

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I read that one. I can't really see how a dropdown control would work for site-based filtering without having an option for literally every site, which sounds awful. The current control is for "read-ness". It wouldn't work to cram sites or types into it. If there is a third "read-ness" state you can think of, then fair enough

Comment: The clickable area was expanded to include the "INBOX (ALL)" text, so that part of your answer has been addressed. Your other point is still valid, though.

Answer (score 5):

> Marking notifications as read/unread

This requirement, and the stickiness of the notification badge unless the user engages in extra steps - compared to the previous behavior, merely viewing the comment dropdown - generates unnecessary extra noise for the average user.

That may not be apparent from committed beta testers.

But as a regular user - SE is a Q&A feed - not a critical app.

**Please keep the cognitive noise level down.**

Searching for "mental health research notifications" brings back plenty of hits, although many of them relate to smartphones (probably because the majority of online interactions are now through them - including potentially many SE users).

Here's [one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4912993/):

> . In addition, the risk group featured a higher rate of error in the Go-Nogo task, due to the negative influence of smartphone push notifications on performance in both risk and nonrisk groups. Furthermore, push notifications affected subsequent performance in the risk group.

p.s. we can always look at the dropdown to see what we might have missed, so this is not fixing anything.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [design](/questions/tagged/design)

«Go to full inbox» partially visible on mobile Chrome (iPadOS):

> [image]

Comment: It's not visible at all when opening the inbox on my screen — it only shows up when I scroll down a little.

Comment: Same problem in Firefox (Ubuntu). Seems like a newly introduced bug, yesterday it was not like this as far as I remember.

Answer (score 4):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

As I see, there are only some numbers of notifications displayed in the inbox out of all possible notifications.

I can see 53 notifications till Jul 02, 2022, displayed when seeing the inbox from https://meta.stackexchange.com

I can see 23 notifications till Sep 14, 2022, displayed when seeing the inbox from https://stackexchange.com

So what are the criteria for displaying the top X number of notifications in the inbox UI?
Is it based on a particular period of time or a particular number of notifications count or the size of the notification message length?

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Clicking "refresh" to receive new entries while the "unread" filter is active causes all entries to be shown- *including* previous entries that have already been marked as read.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) (/ maybe [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) since it's explicitly out of scope?)

I know the announcement specifically states that the chat inbox was *not* updated during this iteration, but... I didn't realise that that meant that if I ever open the notification panel in chat all of my notifications will be marked as read.

Simple steps to reproduce.

1. Mark 1 or more messages unread (in this case I marked 2 as unread).
   [image]
2. Go to a chat server (it doesn't matter which one). There will be a notification of unread items in the inbox (this may take a little bit of time to be picked up if you're doing this in real time). Now, simply click on the inbox to check the notification.
   [image]
3. Return to any location where the new inbox is accessible. There will be no unread notifications in the inbox.
   [image]

---

I had (prior to creating this simple example) gone through and marked several messages unread that I needed to follow up on. With a single click in chat, I ended up undoing the effort I spent to mark the messages I was trying to keep as unread. Is there any way that this behaviour can be prevented during the transition?

Again, I know that chat is specifically out of scope for this first iteration, however, this issue is greatly impacting my ability to use the benefits of this new feature.

Comment: Well, they will get to it at some point, but doubt they can just push a "patch" to do what you ask for. :(

Comment: This doesn't happen if you don't open the inbox in chat

Answer (score 3):

> Are you planning to bring these inbox improvements to chat as well?

Does only mentioning chat here vs chat and area 51 elsewhere mean that there currently aren't plan to update A51's inbox?

Comment: Area51 does not even have any top bar, so yeah it's more than obvious they're not going to touch it, even with a very long stick. :/

Comment: Area51 has issues right now with its topbar and inbox that predate any changes being made here. When these get addressed, we'll try to bring it in sync with the changes here as well.

Comment: @YaakovEllis other devs said, many times, that SE does not and will not make any changes or non critical bug fixes in Area51. Has this policy been changed?

Comment: There are no plans right now for big changes to Area51, but the topbar there is so broken that fixing it might be something that could happen. No promises.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [design](/questions/tagged/design)

Here's a hole under the "Go to full inbox":

> [image: transparent]

So you can see the text while scrolling the list.

Answer (score 3):

[support](/questions/tagged/support) / [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

> - **Real-time inbox refreshing**:
>
>   - All Stack Exchange pages, *except for the inbox that is on the chat rooms listing, Area 51 pages, and stackexchange.com*, will support real time refreshing of the inbox content.
>   - If a new notification arrived while the inbox was opened, the user will have an option to refresh its content manually with a *refresh* button.
>   - We avoid an immediate refresh not to disturb the users while they work on their notifications. This option is also available while working with multiple tabs open at the same time.

Is this a feature that is currently released? Or something that will be released in the future?

If this is to be released in the future, then you can stop reading.

---

However, if currently released, then it does not work as described. There is no "real-time inbox refreshing".  The behaviour I observe is that after the notification inbox is opened *once* on the page and closed, then any further opening will *not* refresh the inbox items. Even if you get the indicator that there are new items in the inbox.

This is *only* valid if you stay on the same page. Basically, it is this behaviour:

[Notifications are not reloaded until a page is reloaded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383585)

However, there is now a button "Refresh" to click. This will load the new items.

This behaviour leads to, quite frankly, ridiculous user experience:

1. You get 1 new notification.
2. You open the inbox and see it. Then close the inbox.
3. You get 1 new notification.
4. You open the inbox and have to click Refresh to see it.

Repeat 3-4 ad infinitum if you are staying on the same page. If you are to a different page/tab you start from 1. again. Refreshing the page also brings you up to 1.

Also, if you just load a page and start from 2. (so, simply open and close, even if you had no notifications) the next notification you get will not be shown after opening the inbox.

Comment: The quote in your answer does say _If a new notification arrived while the inbox was opened_, which can indeed be read as the behavior you describe, i.e., _opened_ means _opened at some moment while on the page, and either closed again or still open_. However, more sensible behavior would indeed be to check if the inbox is _currently open_ and then show the refresh button, otherwise auto-refresh always.

Comment: @Marijn with that reading there is basically no real-time refreshing. It only "refreshes in real-time" (and that's a stretch) until you open the notifications. TBH, I'm kind of baffled by the boast it's real-time given than it's just loading the items when you open. Which is how the old notifications worked, as well. The new ones just stop loading new data on the second open. Which used to be a bug the old notifications had.

Comment: I guess until you open the inbox there is real-time refreshing, in the sense that you open a page, there are no new messages (so you don't click the inbox), you read for a few minutes, then a message is sent to you, and the top bar auto-refreshes to show the new message indicator.

Comment: Which is a feature of the old inbox. You don't think it's a stretch to list it as a new feature?

Comment: I'm not sure that was a feature in the old inbox, as far as I remember sometimes I would open a couple of tabs (for example some linked questions or a few HNQ) while there was a notification, the number would show in all of them, and when I read the notification in one of the tabs it did not disappear in the others. I have not tested it fully but I think the change is that now the other tabs would sync as long as you don't open the inbox on that tab. If it worked the other way around (new notifications added on an already opened page) I don't remember but I think they did not refresh either.

Comment: The notifications did sync. I usually have *many* tabs open on SE. I've not had to go through and clear notifications on each of them. Although if the websocket connection dies, then you might experience problems. Also this acted slightly odd when you had, say, three notifications and opened them all in tabs immediately one after another. The first tab would show two notifications, the second one notification, the last no notifications. Opening the inbox on either would not show any unread items. BTW, this behaviour is still present with the new inbox.

Answer (score 3):

This is a yucky glitch:

[image]

1. Click the inbox
2. Scroll all the way to the bottom
3. (Box is blank as shown)
4. Click away
5. Click the inbox button again
6. (Same state as in 3 is shown)

IMHO there are two issues here:

1. You shouldn't be able to scroll past the end of the feed
2. The scroll position shouldn't be sticky

Comment: The scrolling past end was reported here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384205 However, I didn't know about the sticky scroll.

Comment: I can repro sticky scroll in FF, not in Chrome

Comment: @YaakovEllis still, the first issue is annoying enough on its own, would be nice to have it fixed. (It's the first bug reported, and not even in review)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard agreed, it is on our list of things to address.

Comment: @YaakovEllis in the past developers used to add [tag:status-review] to bug reports, so now when there isn't any, I take it as "this isn't on our radar at all at the moment". :(

Comment: Everything is on our radar. We add status-review when we have done our internal triage and have added it to our list of stuff to evaluate. We have a slight delay on that for these items here, as we are concentrating on the Staging Ground release at the moment. So triage (and status labels) will be coming soon.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [design](/questions/tagged/design) [localization](/questions/tagged/localization)

There's a possibility to get wrong location for notification time point in case of localized sites. Time is shifted down form the envelope icon. E.g. on Stack Overflow in Russian:

> [image: notification time]

Answer (score 3):

My inbox notification count seems to be whacky. I'm seeing this:

1. Notification count shows 5.
2. Open inbox, the only unread notification is a comment to another answer I gave to this question (which had several other comments).
3. I mark it as read.
4. Notification count shows 4.
5. Repeat step 2 (same notification, but maybe it's a different comment being shown?)
6. Repeat step 3.
7. Notification count shows 3.
8. Now there are no unread messages that I can see.

[image]

9. Refresh the page. Now I can see an unread notification (another comment on the same thread):

[image]

Repeat, repeat, repeat...

Comment: At the moment there is an issue with the notification count not always matching the number of shown notifications. This is an old problem with merging mulitple notifications for one post. Unfortunately it is much more visible with the new functionality in place.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

#### Sufficiently old answers show up in the count but not in the unread listing at all.

After letting a number of old answers pile up, even after *trying* to go back through them and catch up, the counter is not at zero... yet listing the inbox shows nothing at all.

Refreshing/reloading has no effect on this behavior, distinguishing it from some other reports here (similarly, it can be distinguished from some other preexisting reports because the scroll bar shows that there's no content in the window that could be reached by scrolling up or down). I have no way that I know of to discover what these phantom messages are and read them (they're far enough back in the full inbox that I've given up before reaching them every time I've tried)

[image: Notification showing 45 unread messages, but an inbox in "unread" mode not listing any contents at all].

Comment: Thank you for reporting it! The first implementation only filters the top 50 messages and does not call the backend. We're aware of it and it is something we have scheduled in our backlog.

Comment: Ah. Is there any alternate way to get this list (including via API call) unrelated to the recent UI changes?

Comment: Yes -  the notifications are visible in the global inbox ("Go to full inbox" button).

Comment: Sorry -- that's not what I meant to ask. I know they're there in the full inbox, but I've been here well over a decade, my inbox is over a thousand pages long, and I have no idea how deep the messages in question are. Having given up on trying to reach them several times, I'm trying to list _only_ unread messages; if the main inbox has a way to do that, I haven't seen it.

Comment: Ok, I got it! ATM it's not possible, but we'll add this feature.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that's not relevant. Before this change, **all** messages became "read" once you opened the inbox without a way to mark any as unread. So no matter how deep you dig, you'll never find old unread items because it does not exist. And since we can't mark items as unread from the full inbox, you also can't even do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

The possibility to (auto) delete messages. Looking at my inbox there is 1184 pages à 20 messages each, sorted in chronological order.

I can't find a reasonable way to search or browse old messages, nor do I quite understand why I would ever want to do that. I've been a member for 12 years and never had the need for such. The messages are sorted by date but only displays month and day, not year. Worse yet it's just one big goo of all messages from every site in the network that I'm a member of.

What am I supposed to do with this? Save for checking messages received during the past week or so, there's no way nor need for me to meaningfully interact with old messages the inbox.

So it would seem that the archived old messages are just useless bloat taking up massive amounts of space on some SE server. The vast majority of it all is just hard-copies of comments archived on the sites anyway. At least delete everything older than 1 year?

Comment: You can access your own inbox replies via API, at least: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox

Comment: @TylerH Why not just deliver a raw database and the "community" can do all the work implementing the site from there. But another point is that this is just a lot of useless info. Yeah someone will say that HD space is cheap... and then the next thing we hear is that some big tech corp needs to buy a new server hall that consumes half a nuclear plant in power consumption. And in the end its common folks who have to pay a steep power bill just so that tech companies can store astronomical amounts of useless garbage. There's no such thing as a free lunch/free social media/free HD space.

Comment: The 'massive amounts of space' is likely not such a big issue, I just tried putting 23680 comment in a text file and that is 3mb, with current storage prices per MB that is around 0.0000486 US dollar.

Comment: @Marijn SE doesn't just have 1 single user.

Comment: That is true, but most of them will not have thousands of comments.

Comment: Also, let's assume that all ~30 million SE users have a 3mb inbox (which they don't), then that would cost around $1500. Stack Exchange, Inc. was bought by Prosus for $1.8 billion, so the storage cost for the inbox is approximately 0% of the company's value.

Comment: @Lundin I agree it would be better if they were searchable because then there'd be immediate use for users. Just wanted to point out that there was at least _some_ way to make use of them.

Comment: Even if ~30 million SE users have a 3MB inbox, that being a total of 90 TB of data... That's ___nothing___ compared to the amount of data sites like YouTube need to store. A drop in a bucket. I'm __strongly__ opposed to just deleting older notifications. I've searched through my notifications a few times over the past year. I don't see a very strong reason to _remove_ it.

Comment: "it all is just hard-copies of comments" Are you sure? It likely is just links to them. When a comment is deleted, so is the notification.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Pretty sure, since when you write a comment then edit it, I don't think the edited part appears in the notification. (This text in parenthesis here was added as and edit after I notified you.)

Comment: @Lundin The notification doesn't show the full comment, it only shows *"@CrisLuengo Pretty sure, since when you write a comment then edit it, I don't think the edite..."* But I believe you. I guess I would have implemented it differently. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yet another reason why saving these messages doesn't make any sense then.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

### Items are still marked as read if you choose not to navigate away from an unfinished post

To reproduce:

1. have at least one unread notification in your inbox
2. start writing a new question
3. click to the notification to navigate to it
4. decline navigating away from the unfinished post when prompted
5. notification is marked as read even though you never navigated to it

Comment: The code handling marking the item as read can't know that you changed your mind and didn't actually navigate to the link. Maybe with some complex hax it's possible to know, but I don't think the devs should spend their time on it.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard how could you know that without knowing the code? I'll leave it up to the Devs to decide if it's worth fixing.

Comment: When you click on the notification, it will always be marked as read. This is how it is supposed to work. And changing it so that it will only retroactively mark it as read once the user view the page is not something practical in this scenario (there are a lot more ways in which that can break down, and for almost every case it is over-engineering).

Comment: @YaakovEllis thanks for clarifying that! There should be mechanism, the same one for the prompt, that could make this simple... But it is an extra thing to break like you said.

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

The Filter "INBOX (UNREAD)" and the "INBOX (ALL)" is all caps, the dropdown uses titlecase so the selection would be consistent if it was the same.

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [design](/questions/tagged/design)

### iOS 16.1.2 on iPhone 14 Pro Max

Marking or unmarking as read has a small area in which it works. I have large fingers, so I need to zoom (pinch) into the page to click the button.

The yellow area in the photo below always works, but clicking the larger blue area often takes you to the post.

Could we extend the area considered to be part of the mark/unmark action? There is plenty of space to go to the post by clicking more to the left.

[image: area]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

When scrolling with the mouse wheel while pointing within the inbox window, I expect the inbox window to scroll, not the main page.

I'm on macOS+Safari. Sometimes the main window scrolls, sometimes the inbox window scrolls. It is rather unpredictable. Move the mouse a bit and try again usually works. — This is not about the main page scrolling when you get to the end of the window scroll range, it is the window not scrolling when it should.

I had never before tried to scroll the achievements window, but I notice now that it has the same unpredictable behavior. The community window (rightmost button on the top bar) does too.

Comment: I'm not experiencing this problem in Chrome (Version 107) on Mac OS 13.0 (Ventura) – and I've never encountered problems with it in Firefox on Windows either... If anyone else is able to reproduce this behavior, then I would guess that it's a Safari-specific issue.

Comment: In any case, I doubt this would be related to the inbox improvements, especially since I don't think the other top-bar dropdowns were affected by the changes to the inbox... so I suspect this should be reported as a separate bug, if anything.

Comment: @V2Blast It has never been an issue before because we used to see many more inbox items in the menu without scrolling. I don't remember ever trying to scroll any of those windows before, it has become necessary because of the much larger vertical dimension of each inbox item in the new inbox.

Comment: @V2Blast try to scroll to the end, then scroll more, and the main page will scroll instead. That's what I get with Chrome under Win10.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard: True, but I figure that's the expected behavior, so I assumed that's not the issue Cris Luengo was reporting. I could be wrong there.

Comment: If you hit either the top or bottom of the drop menu scroll, the main page will then move instead, if possible, in the same direction. This, as far as I can recall, has always been Mac/Safari behaviour on all sites, not just SE, even if it isn't universal across browsers [I've never really used anything else so not noticed.] I've always considered it OK most times, but if you rapid-scroll, it's irritating as you lose your place on the main window.

Comment: @Tetsujin What I observe is not that. It is the window not scrolling when it should, and the main window scrolling instead.

Comment: @CrisLuengo can't reproduce, you better create a gif or a video and show it. Might be something on your side, e.g. userscript going rogue.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Ok, I’ll try to do that later today then.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [design](/questions/tagged/design)

1. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (thanks, let me mark this for you)
   I use a custom page scale in a browser because most of the modern sites are too huge and it results in the filter drop­down being misaligned with the arrow:

   [image: Inbox filter drop­down is horizontally in the middle]
2. Also if you take a closer look at the filter drop­down, the triangle at the top-left is misaligned as well and creates a hole in a left border (at any scale):

   [image: Inbox filter drop­down, 10x zoom of top-left corner]
   <sup>(I doubt this worth a separate post)</sup>

   **Edit:**
   Seems like it's an actual bug, here's how it looked like in the announcement post:

   [image: Inbox filter drop­down from the announcement post]

Comment: SE never supported zooming/scaling of that sort, and I can't see how it's possible to support such thing. The design is based on specific size, and breaking that with external tools will break the design.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, since I'm not seeing the whole site turning apart I think it's pretty much supported. It's not an external tool, it's a standard browser feature. And the design is not based on specific size either, it's responsive. This could be fixed as easy as making the dropdown position relative to the arrow.

Comment: What browser and OS (and what versions of them) are you encountering this issue in?

Comment: @V2Blast I'm on Vivaldi 3.3 (Chrome 85) now, there are no errors in a Console after opening the dropdown (and at all). Not sure the OS is relevant here, but it's Windows 7 SP1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting way too many messages now. The problem is that before all comments or answers on a single question were lumped together in a 'you have something on this question' message. Now I get a message for every single comment. If people are being being very talkative on a question I post it quickly builds up to an excessive number of notifications.

I know I can mark everything as read, but that risks my missing something I care about, such as a useful answer to a different question, in the flood of comments I mostly don't care about, and which I'm going to read all at once if I do.

Id like to see one notification if there is a comment on a question or answer of mine, and only one per question/answer no matter how many comments are made. If not by default then at least as an option I can select.

I'd sort of like the same option to combine all answers to a single question into one notification, but I don't feel nearly as strongly about that as I do getting rid of clutter from excessive comments where I need to click each comment one after another despite reading all the comments at once.

Comment: "The problem is that before all comments or answers on a single question were lumped together in a 'you have something on this question' message. Now I get a message for every single comment. If people are being being very talkative on a question I post it quickly builds up to an excessive number of notifications." – I'm pretty sure the same number of notifications is displayed now as were displayed before – and the notifications for multiple comments on the same post are merged together, as before. The one thing that's changed is that they're not all marked as read when you open the inbox...

Comment: ...Because of that, there's currently a suboptimal experience where you only see one of those notifications at a time in the inbox dropdown, and can only mark them as read one by one (unless you click "Mark all read", of course) – marking one notification as read unmerges it from the remaining unread notifications, but the notifications you can actually see don't update until you refresh the inbox. Other answers to this post already cover that issue – but at this point, if you have new feedback that's not already covered by one of the existing answers, please post it as a new question instead.

Answer (score 0):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

Some of the notifications are missing in the new Inbox.

In the below image, all the possible notifications from my [Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com) (by clicking on the "Go to full inbox" link at the bottom of the inbox) are displayed on the left-hand side. Compared to that some of the notifications are missing in the new Inbox.

I didn't remember the same approach was exists in the previous inbox UI.
So, is this a bug or the existing functionality?

**Screenshot from stackexchange.com:**

[image: notifications are missing in the new inbox]

Comment: As far as I can tell, it was always like that, the inbox "collapse" several  comments on same post into one notification to avoid cluttering it.

Comment: Yep, what Shadow said. This confused me at first as well, since I didn't realize the inbox was doing this before... It's just that it's more confusing behavior when notifications are individually marked read/unread, since only the visible (most recent) notification is currently marked read when you click on it.

Comment: As [Yaakov's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384148/inbox-improvements-are-live/384212#comment1281411_384212) on [Stu's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384212/335251) states: "We definitely have "figure out a better way to handle merged notifications" on our list of things to address".

Answer (score 0):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [design](/questions/tagged/design) [localization](/questions/tagged/localization)

Weird dropdown icon position in case of long translated strings:

> [image]

Screenshot was taken from [StackOverflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)

Stretching the top element on the whole line will also combine the drop-down and close buttons, on mobile, making it harder to tap the right one. However, even with narrow size tapping the drop-down icon may accidentally affect the "Mark all as read" link.

> [image: Android inbox]

Comment: You can repro on any site if you edit the text in the browser's Developer Tools ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b9y5.png)). Apparently, when the width of the menu cannot fit both elements, the dropdown gets stretched to fill the entire width (since the link is moved to the second line anyway). I'm not sure this is considered a bug though. Do you think it would look better like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/922UA.png)?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine narrowed items are better, explanation added to the post body.

Comment: That's fair. Perhaps making the whole dropdown (not just the button) clickable would be a decent solution.

Answer (score -2):

> **Can I keep the current inbox functionality?**
>
> No. [...]

This may seem petty, but please: when you are communicating design changes, don't tell us they are "improvements" unless they are objectively improvements for everyone. If you can foresee that some people will want to keep the old behaviour, then you already know that there are users who will not consider the change to be an improvement.

If you think those people are few enough that it's not worth giving us an option to keep the old behaviour (unless, apparently, enough of us whinge about it), then OK, it sounds like you have justified to yourself that the change is worth making on balance. But for those of us who consider the change to be a degradation (see some of the other answers here for why we think that), you telling us it's an improvement is not going to make us think otherwise. But it might make us think that you don't care what we think.

So please, don't toot your own horn. If something is really an improvement, trust your users to recognise it as one.

Comment: By this criteria, we can never call anything an improvement. Someone [will always](https://xkcd.com/1172/) want to keep things as-is. Not intending to insult anyone, and we do care. Sorry that it was taken that way.

Comment: Yeah, this seems pedantic. It's fair enough to call something an improvement if it is being done in good faith with the goal of improving something, and most people would see it that way.

Comment: I agree with @Yaakov here. The fact we can now mark inbox items as read/unread alone is a big leap forward. The way it's done, the bugs, the things that can still be improved are a different story, but overall, it's moving forward.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I already could mark inbox items as read, with two clicks; now it takes three and one of them is a tiny icon. That is not forwards.

Comment: @YaakovEllis I don't agree. If you add a new option and some people want to use it while others don't have to, that objectively doesn't make anyone worse off. In that case you can objectively call it an improvement. If you change the behaviour to make it worse for some people, but you tell us it is an improvement, that makes it sound like you didn't consider those people when making the change.

Comment: It's impossible to make everyone happy, in anything, in any aspect.

Comment: Case in point, I have already opened my inbox, navigated to this comment thread, and responded to your comment, yet the site tells me I still have two unread items in my inbox, and shows one unread item when I click on it, and it's this comment thread. That is not an improvement, it is a degradation; being told it is an improvement just makes me think you don't know what the change means or you don't care.

Comment: After posting another comment now it says I have *three*, while still only showing one. "You can't make everyone happy" is a vacuous truism, not a sensible response to negative feedback.

Comment: @kaya3 that one is actually under review, you can skim through the answers here, and you'll find it.