# Automatically refresh the global inbox

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox

That'd be great to automatically refresh the global inbox, instead of having the user manually click on the "refresh" button:

[image]

Comment: I previously posted it as an [answer to the announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384311/377214). Of note, the Refresh button didn't exist at the time I posted that.