# Inbox icon indicates an unread message, but no messages are shown under "unread"

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox

I've noticed a case where my inbox icon indicated an unread message (1 in red), but no messages were shown under "unread":

[image]

I don't know how to reproduce. Maybe it's because I was already on the page where the new message came from.

My network was fine. Chrome version 108.0.5359.125 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: I get this all the time when i have multiple tabs open and return to a tab after marking all as read in another tab.

Comment: I just had this happen to me. I had to go to my Inbox in order to clear it. It's probably relevant that I had multiple notifications for comments on the same answer and only the latest one was visible from the dropdown.

Comment: I've seen this when a Comment is edited.  A new notification goes out, but the edited Comment is considered read on the list if it was read before the edit.

Comment: This was reported over on the inbox changes announcement here: [Inbox improvements are live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384311)

Comment: This still happens regularly.

Comment: I've had a "stuck" icon for over a week, and would love to know how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 4):

I do not have an answer as to the root cause, but there is a "solution" that worked for me.  The "mark all read" link (you can see it in the dropdown in the video--it's on the top right of the dropdown panel) successfully cleared the update indicator.

I don't like doing this, because I feel uneasy about possibly having missed something, but I guess it's better than having a false (or possibly just un-actionable) indication of updates.

This happened to me in Safari, Version 16.5.1 (18615.2.9.11.7).