# How can I find unread messages in the Stack Exchange inbox?

Tags: support, global-inbox

Usually I just scroll down and find the unread messages and click on the items. This way I am done in a minute.

Today I did that and it still says that I have 3 unread messages. I clicked the "view full inbox" button at the bottom. Then I looked for something to sort by unread or click to view all unread. But alas there was no button to help find the unread messages.

#### How can I find unread messages in the Stack Exchange inbox?

Comment: Try clicking on the "Inbox (All))" Its a dropdown menu. That has a dropdown menu that lets you filter only unread messages

Comment: thanks your comment answered the question 100%. i guess i could copy/paste it into an answer.

Comment: arg. i clicked "unread" like you said. and the window was empty. so in frustration i clicked "mark all as read" and then the count went from 3 to 0. so now i lost the three unread. :( i guess i will not know what those messages were. (my fault i know)

Comment: OH - if you have more than one window, sometimes it dosen't autorefresh between windows/tabs

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385090/inbox-icon-indicates-an-unread-message-but-no-messages-are-shown-under-unread

Comment: I guess the behavior I saw was caused by the bug that @anx linked to

Answer (score 5):

[image]

You click on the Inbox(ALL) and change it to unread.Sometimes with more than one tab, it won't autorefresh, or you'll see a (X) with a number on the side with (refresh), which means the inbox is out of date. You're unlikely to have *lost* an unread message by it being automatically marked read

Comment: Well it does not seem to be *locally* out of date - for me, the non-zero notification count despite empty unread list persists beyond clearing storage and logging in again.

Comment: that might be a different bug - I've never had that yet