# I have a permanent indicator of 3 unread messages in Inbox

Tags: support, notifications, global-inbox

**EDIT**
I learned about selecting only *Unread messages* in my Inbox [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393542/232130).
When I tried it, there were no messages shown, but [selecting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394652/i-have-a-permanent-indicator-of-3-unread-messages-in-inbox#comment1319383_394652) *Mark all as read* removed the indicator, so the issue was resolved. I then found this is exactly what was asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385090/232130) and answered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391025/232130).
So this one is actually a dupe, and [Inbox icon indicates an unread message, but no messages are shown under "unread"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385090/inbox-icon-indicates-an-unread-message-but-no-messages-are-shown-under-unread) is a better reference for that.
Plus, I guess [How can I view unread messages?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393526/how-can-i-view-unread-messages) should also be tagged as a dupe of the first one.

---

At the top right of my SE sites, I have a permanent indictor of at least 3 unread messages in my Inbox. Whenever I get new messages, that number increases accordingly, but it never goes below 3 (as if it were my new zero).
I cannot find any unread message, so I suspect it is a bug.
Why is that?
Can it be fixed?
Or how can I go straight to those unread messages, in case it is not a bug, so they reset to zero?