# Inbox item doesn't appear until one has clicked on another inbox item

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox

Example of inbox item ("that doesn't seem like [...]") that doesn't appear until one has clicked on another inbox item ("it will still be the same [...]"):

[image]

Comment: This is known and expected. I believe it's been reported multiple times on both MSO and MSE, and in chat. SE developers are aware. I thought it was marked [tag:status-planed], but I'm not sure about that. Alternative interactions are A) to click "Mark all read", which will, unsurprisingly, marks all of your inbox messages as read; or B) click on the message icon to mark one as read and then click the "Refresh" button to see the others which were for the same post and thing.

Comment: I also repro this frequently. A third workaround to add to Makyen's list is to go to the "full inbox". In my experience, the additional inbox items do show up there, and can be easily dismissed.

Comment: Yes, we see that the issue affects the community and we track it in our backlog. It happens when multiple notifications for a single post are "merged" into one.

Comment: @marrados can you please disable the merging feature?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inbox improvements are live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384148/inbox-improvements-are-live) This is covered in the following answers on that question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384162/271271, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384189/271271, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384212/271271, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384310/271271, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384148/inbox-improvements-are-live/384212#comment1281411_384212, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385543/271271, and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384211/271271