# How to make the inbox show all notifications

Tags: support, notifications, global-inbox

How can I make the inbox preview all my notifications?

At the moment, it will show me a red number e.g. 4, but when I click it, I only see one unread notification. The reason is because all 4 notifications are comments or answers posted on the same question page. I would like to see the preview of all the comments and answers even if they're from the same question page.

How can I make it do that?

Comment: FYI: [Inbox item doesn't appear until one has clicked on another inbox item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385463/178179)

Comment: @minseong The company has said that how the inbox works is currently in flux. There was an update late last year, which brought us to the current point. The company has said that there will be another update sometime in the semi-near future. The issue which you are having is something that's been reported multiple times over the last few months. They are aware of it. Hopefully, they'll change it such that it's easier to use than it currently is.

Comment: Related [Inbox improvements are live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384148/inbox-improvements-are-live) The following answers on that question are related to this issue: [384162](/a/384162/271271), [384189](/a/384189/271271), [384212](/a/384212/271271), [384310](/a/384310/271271), [385543](/a/385543/271271), and [384211](/a/384211/271271). There are multiple related comments on that question and answers, but of particular note is [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384148/inbox-improvements-are-live/384212#comment1281411_384212)

Answer (score 4):

Scroll down a little in the drop-down and click on [Go to full inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox) . There you can see all your notifications, even those that would normally be grouped into a single line in your drop-down inbox.

Comment: I mean how can I make the drop-down show me all the notifications?

Comment: Either by making/installing a userscript or by writing a feature request so compelling they change how it works.