# Tapping on the message from inbox doesn’t mark it read anymore

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox, ios

Tapping on the message from inbox doesn’t mark it read anymore. Is it desired behavior?

> [image]

As far as I remember before inbox renewal, tapping on the item led to mark that item read (simultaneously with the redirecting to target object). Now only the redirection is done, and I need to manually tap on envelope icon to mark the message as read.

Tested on iPadOS 16.2, Google Chrome

Not reproducible on Android.

According to the comments below looks like an Apple products related issue.

Here's additional animation to see how it "works":

> [image]

Comment: It's possible you received multiple comments on the same post. The dropdown will initially consolidate those multiple notifications into a single entry, but once you've read the first one, the notifications for the other comments will remain unread and the read one will be separated.

Comment: I think you can reproduce on this question

Comment: ...since I just commented on it twice

Comment: No repro, maybe some userscript.

Comment: I tried on several different desktop browsers.  You did not mention it was iOS in the original revision. I don't have that handy at the moment, so I cannot easily check there.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I never used userscripts. Especially on iPad.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ I frequently have this problem, too. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. (Firefox 102.7 ESR on macOS 11.7)

Comment: Related announcement: [Inbox improvements are live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/335251). Left-clicking or middle-clicking an unread notification should mark it as read, though right-clicking it won't. Not sure if this is an iPad-/iOS-specific issue, or if it's the same issue indicated by Sonic's first comment (which has also been reported in an answer on the announcement I linked).

Comment: @V2Blast Left clicking also supposed to work for inbox notifications about followed posts? I always have to manually mark them as read. Left click never works for them.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yep, it should work. It seems to work when I tested it just now by marking a followed-post notification (for a new answer on it) as unread, and then left-clicked on it – it did mark it as read for me.

Comment: @V2Blast Not working for me with Firefox/macOS https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG3hh.gif

Comment: This has *never* worked for me.  I always have to click mark as read.  Safari, Mac OS Ventura (13.1).

Comment: As for the bug itself, probably the tap action of iOS sends different code to the browser, and SE "listens" only to codes of mouse click events in the part responsible to mark as read.