# Inbox only shows one message if two replies are received close together

Tags: bug, top-bar, global-inbox

I've noticed this a few times now with the new "sticky" inbox. I'll get two comment reply notifications close together, which will show a `2` badge over my inbox icon in the top bar.

When I open the inbox though, it will only show one reply. If I mark that reply as read, I need to close the overlay, then reopen it to see the other notification in order to mark it as read.

Now, I could probably just use the "Mark all as read" button to skip needing to open it a second time, but this seems like buggy behavior. I do not know what exactly causes it since I don't receive replies often enough to notice a pattern. It seems to be when I receive multiple replies from the same question though.

Comment: [related comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385959/tapping-on-the-message-from-inbox-doesn-t-mark-it-read-anymore#comment1286956_385959)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ That seems very unintuitive. If that's what's happening, I don't remember it being obvious that they were being consolidated, so it just looks like one's missing.

Comment: I doubt you're the only one who hates the click-fest that is the new inbox. People asked for the old one back. That, as with all the recent interface changes - crappy new vote arrows etc - was just handed down from on high with little to do but accept them. I could find you appropriate links, but tbh, all it will do is make you more annoyed ;))

Comment: This is a known issue with the [inbox improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384148/inbox-improvements-are-live) (as a result of the preexisting behavior where notifications of the same type associated with the same post get merged together). It's definitely not an ideal user experience, and something the devs are planning to improve. (I think there's a separate post somewhere reporting the same issue that didn't end up getting closed as a duplicate of that announcement...)