# Multiple answers to the same question doesn't clear in inbox count

Tags: support, bug, comments, global-inbox

I just verified that it doesn't work.

I tried to answer a question on SO. The OP put 2 comments under my answer, which showed "2" in the "Recent inbox messages".

When I click the button, I see only one line—so far so good. I clicked this line with the right mouse button and then went to the question. I looked at the comments and close the tab—nothing else to do there.

When I returned back to the SO page, I saw that the number went down to 1.

Is this how it is supposed to be?

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding a few things. 1) From your title, did you provide multiple answers to a single question? The question body suggests that you only gave one answer. 2) What count did you expect to clear? 3) From you body, what did you verify doesn't work? 4) What button did you click? 5) What "one line" did you see? 6) What number went down to 1?

Comment: Duplicate of [this feature request answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384162/323179). Just wait until it's comments and there are 15 or so of them.

Comment: @bobble, 1. No - 1 answer to a 1 question. 3. Inbox message count. 3. Inbo message count should be 0 - I visited the site so count should be 0 and everything should become "read". 4. Inbox messages. 5. Clicking on "Inbox messages" I see one line for both replies.  6. Number of unread messages.

Comment: @Laurel, Right now on this question I see a "2" unread inbox messages. That number should be 0 - I am on the page and I'm reading them...

Comment: @Laurel, are you saying that this behavior is correct? and I should see `number of messages - 1` instead of clear them up to 0? This is wrong - I read the messages in my Inbox. All of them. Why I have any extra?

Comment: Every time you click on an unread message/envelope in your inbox, it usually decreases the count of the total unread messages by one. Sometimes (different bug report) it doesn't even do that and the message is still unread. So yes, you would have to reload the page 15 times to "read" all 15 comments since they're all nested. Visiting the page by any other means does not affect the inbox in any way.

Comment: @Laurel, but then why do you squish all those replies and present them as "1"? What hidden purpose you have to do that?

Comment: @Igor Lots of us think the current operation is broken from a usability POV. Personally, I'm the author of a question that's had about 300 comments since it was posted after the inbox changes, so I *certainly* sympathize. This issue has previously been reported to SE. They've said that their intent is to have another revision of how the inbox works in the not too distant future, but when is unclear.

Comment: Related [Inbox improvements are live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384148/inbox-improvements-are-live) The following answers on that question are related to this issue: [384162](/a/384162/271271), [384189](/a/384189/271271), [384212](/a/384212/271271), [384310](/a/384310/271271), [385543](/a/385543/271271), and [384211](/a/384211/271271). There are multiple related comments on that question and answers, but of particular note is [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384148/inbox-improvements-are-live/384212#comment1281411_384212)