# Notifications not being marked as read

Tags: support, comments, notifications, global-inbox

I see this has been asked historically a few times over the years, but this is a new behavior for me since about the past couple of weeks or months or so.

I get comment notifications, and when I click them it goes to the comment, but it doesn't mark the notification as read, or at least not consistently so.

My suspicion is that when the notification is for multiple comments on post, you have to click the notification once for each individual comment the notification is tied to. That is not necessarily a bad thing, but just linking to the earliest comment for the notification, one would naturally see that there are other comments below that in the thread, so there isn't any need to keep the notification live.

Or maybe it is a problem with my browser (up-to-date Chrome on fully up-to-date Windows desktop and Android)? I doubt that though. It seems like a change in the Stack Exchange code.

Comment: "My suspicion is that when the notification is for multiple comments on post, you have to click the notification once for each individual comment the notification is tied to." – Your suspicion is correct. Multiple unread notifications for comments on the same post are merged into a single visible entry (and multiple read notifications are also merged with one another in the same way). – As of the [recent inbox improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/335251), only the visible comment is marked read when clicked; this is an issue that was reported there, and we're aware of it.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of another recent post that more clearly describes the same issue. Hope that's okay :)