# Lots of empty space in inbox

Tags: bug, design, global-inbox

> [image]

When I scroll to the bottom of my inbox, there is a ton of empty space. It's not that I don't have a lot of notifications; my full inbox has plenty of stuff. Is it supposed to look like this? In any case, I think the space should be cropped.

The achievements don't have this problem:

[image]

Also reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384205/1213814).

Comment: Also previously reported in a few of the answers on this announcement: [Inbox improvements are live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/335251) (e.g. [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384205/335251) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384442/335251))

Comment: I’m pretty sure Alexei reported this one too. But it may have been in the middle of one of his spurts of dozens of frivolous, valid-but-will-probably-never-be-fixed reports. And he self-deleted several IIRC. :-)