# New network top-bar cuts off achievement/inbox dialogue

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, global-inbox, achievements-dialog

The new top-bar looks like this:

> [image]

But when I click the `inbox` or `achievement` button, it does this:

| Inbox | Achievements |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

I'm not super zoomed in or anything, but the box still gets cut off by the left side of the screen.

Also, there's no magnifying bar next to the search box, which looks weird.

Are others having this problem? Can it be fixed?

Comment: Wait, am I crazy? The top-bar now looks the way it used to be...

Comment: It's pretty common for changes to leak before being actually done. That's most likely the case here. Sometimes it's on purpose to test in production how it looks like, sometimes an honest mistake.

Comment: These buttons from toolbar belong to [chat.se](https://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There haven't been any changes to the top bar either on the stackexchange.com network site or on chat.SE/chat.SO/chat.MSO recently, as far as I know. I think the last time the network site's top bar was touched was when [the inbox improvements went live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/335251), which included updates to the inbox dropdown on the network site (but not on chat subdomains).